# What is the recovery trajectory for numbness preceding shingles?

Tags: neuropathy, numbness, shingles

When a mild, small shingles outbreak (8-10 square inches) is preceded by a few days of numbness that covers the affected area, what are the expectations for normal feeling to return after the shingles lesions have run their course?

[One reference](https://www.nia.nih.gov/health/shingles#long-term) refers to long term pain, but not to post-blister numbness.

[This reference](https://ada.com/signs-of-shingles/) also mentions numbness as a pre-blister symptom.

There is a lot on the net about shingles, but the post-blister recovery information focuses on pain rather than numbness.  Given a choice, most people would rather numbness than pain, but given the mechanism of infection by herpes zoster, I am curious about reasonable expectations for nerves returning to normal function.

How long should one expect the numbness to last?

Comment: Welcome to Medical Sciences! Please take the [tour] and read the [help]. For [reasons mentioned in this post](https://medicalsciences.meta.stackexchange.com/q/411) and in [ask], we require some degree of prior research when asking questions. *See [this list of helpful resources](https://medicalsciences.meta.stackexchange.com/a/784)*. Please help us to help you and [edit] your question to provide more information on what you have read on this subject, what made you ask this question, and any problems you are having understanding your research. If you found nothing, what did you Google?

Comment: Very well.  I have been looking, and will look again and create a bibliography of resources which did not answer the question.  Feel free to close this question.

Comment: A single link to what you've read so far would have sufficed, or even just telling us what you've searched for. You'll find that most of the science and academic sites have the same prior research requirement we do. The purpose is to prevent trivial, low-quality "gimme the codez" questions.

Comment: Not a bibliography, but two references in which I did not find an answer.  I've looked further, but there may be a simple search I've overlooked.  IMO, anecdotal information is ok as an answer.

Comment: Your edits are perfectly fine. We don't need a bibliography, just some evidence you actually spent some time on the question. We'll see what answers you get but anecdotal answers aren't ok per site rules.

Comment: Ok.  I don't have access to NEJM or any neurobiology journals.  I suspect there isn't much scholarship on this issue, since it isn't disabling like chronic pain.  My MD friends haven't had much info either.  Maybe there is no good forum for this question.

Comment: I suspect you're right that there isn't a lot of scholarship on this particular question. Even without paid access to journals you should be able to find abstracts of journal articles at no cost -- if they exist. I think it's probably the kind of question that would find more useful information on a patient support forum. I don't know if there are any for shingles but I would look for them.